# h:dataTable inside ui:repeat, how specify render id from f:ajax?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have:

```xml
<ui:repeat id="projectsTable" var="project" value="#{projectsBacking.projectList}">
  #{project.id}
  <h:dataTable id="usersAssignedToProject#{project.id}" var="appUser" value="#{projectsBacking.getAllUsersAssignedToProject(project)}">
    #{project.id}
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{appUser.getUsername()}"/>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Using `<f:ajax>` I can not render `h:dataTable` with given id, can someone explain me what is wrong in this code? When I checked by FireBug `<table id="usersAssignedToProject">`, but in client side `#{project.id}` was printed (before and inside datatable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of id of h:dataTable is resolved when components tree is being build, but var `project` is only available on render response.
Try using `c:forEach` in this case instead of `ui:repeat`.

More information on this:
https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat